# Organising animations in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gamekit

I have a number of different scenes in Swift. Each scene animates a number of objects briefly. These objects are disparate and all animate in their own unique ways.

The issue is that now I have lines and lines of code for each scene, all of which govern a different SKAction. Is there a way to minify this kind of code, or to restructure the code so that we put it all in one place (and draw from it somewhere else)?

One of my ideas is to make all of the animated nodes a specific class, like AnimatedNode, and then put all the animations in there; as separate functions. This would effectively remove the code from the scene.swift file. Is this the best I can do, or is there some other approach to this that I don't see?

EDIT: My animation code runs 100+ lines across every scene, but as an example of how animations are performed on one such node, this is what it looks like:

```
// can
        let can = bgNode.childNode(withName: "can")
        let tip = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(10)), duration: 0.5)
        let tipSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("pot", waitForCompletion: false)
        can?.run(SKAction.sequence([tip, tipSound, tip.reversed()]))
```

Comment: Could you please show some code to be `minified`?

Comment: Do not minify code. But you can put the animation routines in an `extension`. Putting groups of methods in extensions not only keep your code logically organized, but lets you "collapse" that extension when you're focusing on other portions of your code. Or you can put it in separate class (especially if there's any reuse). I think we'd have to see some sample routines and see what you're proposing to do with those functions.

Comment: I've added more information above!

Comment: You can define actions in action editor. That will *minify* your code

Comment: Yes, in this situation, I would use the action editor.  It would create a separate SKS file that allows you to setup the timeline of your actions, and loading the action is super easy.  `let action = SKAction(named:"myAction")` see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction for more details.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon-- I don't see how to call the actions I create in Action Editor programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

SKActions were meant to be re-used or at least pre-loaded. Your idea is good, because cluttering your scenes with the same code over and over is poor design.

You can make an ActionManager, that has properties for each action you want to run already pre-loaded as a property.. this will increase performance of your game, especially if you are using it more than once.

There are multiple ways to do this, but a plain function (though not as performant as properties) is a good way to at least organize your code.

Comment: Thanks. By ActionManager, do you mean just a separate class or library which has various functions that are pulled into the game scene file?

Comment: An "ActionManager" is really not needed, a simple extension class would suffice and keep in line with the overall behavior of how SKActions are implemented.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Could you provide an example of how this would be done? What would I be extending?

Comment: @illuminatedtype, you would extend SKAction, and use static functions to return a new SKAction object

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That makes sense, thank you! Would I do that in a separate file, which simply extends that class?

Comment: @illuminatedtype yup, keep it organized.  I would really learn how to use the action editor though